# How to sum *count* subqueries with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, count, sqlalchemy, subquery

I have the following models in my DB (Flask-SQLALchemy, declarative approach, simplified):

```
class Player(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    ...

class Game(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    creator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('player.id'))
    creator = db.relationship(Player, foreign_keys='Game.creator_id')
    opponent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('player.id'))
    opponent = db.relationship(Player, foreign_keys='Game.opponent_id')
    winner = db.Column(db.Enum('creator', 'opponent'))
```

Each game may be either won, lost or ended in draw.
I need to get players sorting them by "win rate" - i.e.:

- if player created a game and that game's winner is `creator`, it is considered win;
- if the player was invited to game as opponent and game's winner is `opponent`, it is also considered win;
- other games where this player participated are considered lost games.

So my algorithm is as follows:

```
@hybrid_property
def winrate(self):
    games = Game.query.filter(or_(
        Game.creator_id == self.id,
        Game.opponent_id == self.id,
    ))
    count = 0
    wins = 0
    for game in games:
        count += 1
        if game.creator_id == self.id and game.winner == 'creator':
            wins += 1
        elif game.opponent_id == self.id and game.winner == 'opponent':
            wins += 1
    if count == 0:
        return 0
    return wins / count
```

This approach works when I want to determine win rate for particular player; but it fails when I want to sort players by win rate.
I tried to rewrite it in SQL and got something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM player
ORDER BY ((SELECT count(g1.id) FROM game g1
    WHERE g1.creator_id = player.id AND g1.winner = 'creator'
) + (SELECT count(g2.id) FROM game g2
    WHERE g2.opponent_id = player.id AND g2.winner = 'opponent'
)) / (SELECT count(g3.id) FROM game g3
    WHERE player.id IN (g3.creator_id, g3.opponent_id)
)
```

This doesn't handle players without games but should work in general. Players without games can be probably handled with MySQL `CASE` statement.

But the problem is that I cannot figure how do I encode this SQL using SQLAlchemy.
Here is a (simplified) code I try to use:

```
@winrate.expression
def winrate(cls):
    cnt = Game.query.filter(
        cls.id.in_(Game.creator_id, Game.opponent_id)
    ).with_entities(func.count(Game.id))
    won = Game.query.filter(
        or_(
            and_(
                Game.creator_id == cls.id,
                Game.winner == 'creator',
            ),
            and_(
                Game.opponent_id == cls.id,
                Game.winner == 'opponent',
            ),
        )
    )
    return case([
        (count == 0, 0),
    ], else_ = (
        won / count
    ))
```

This code fails when it comes to `won / count` line telling me that `Query` cannot be divided by `Query`. I tried using subqueries but without any success.

How should I implement it? Or maybe I should use some kind of joins/whatever? (DB scheme cannot be changed.)

Comment: without actually looking or thinking too hard about this: `won.scalar() / count.scalar()`?  `Query.scalar()` produces a scalar subquery, which is a clause element

Comment: Query.scalar() returns number, not subquery.

Comment: ah, sorry, i meant `Query.as_scalar()`  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try working with core expressions instead of orm queries:

```
class Player(..):
    # ...
    @winrate.expression
    def _winrate(cls):
        cnt = (
            select([db.func.count(Game.id)])
            .where(
                db.or_(
                    Game.creator_id == cls.id,
                    Game.opponent_id == cls.id,
                ))
            .label("cnt")
        )
        won = (
            select([db.func.count(Game.id)])
            .where(
                db.or_(
                    db.and_(Game.creator_id == cls.id,
                            Game.winner == 'creator'),
                    db.and_(Game.opponent_id == cls.id,
                            Game.winner == 'opponent'),
                ))
            .label("cnt")
        )

        return db.case(
            [(cnt == 0, 0)],
            else_ = db.cast(won, db.Numeric) / cnt
        )
# ...
q = session.query(Player).order_by(Player.winrate.desc())
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That worked. My only change was to use `db.select` instead of just `select`, but should not be critical.